# Angular $resource with multiple select

Tags: angularjs, resources, slim, multi-select

I'm using Angular `$resource` and having a simple form with some inputs and a multiple select, for example:

```
<select ng-model="item.selectedItems" multiple>
  <option value="bla">Bla</option>
  <option value="bla2">Bla2</option>
</select>
```

Now when I selected all the items in the multiple select and do `item.$save` in my code on submit, the url called is

```
http://domain.com/api/items?field1=text&selectedItems=bla&selectedItems=bla2
```

However, I want this url to be

```
http://domain.com/api/items?field1=text&selectedItems[]=bla&selectedItems[]=bla2
```

just like I was having with a regular

```
<select name="selectedItems[]">
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Using `ng-model="item.selectedItems[]"` didn't work.

I'm using Slim Framework as backend and it just replaces the `selectedItems` parameter with the last in the url.

Comment: Actually it's not Slim that replaces the parameter, this is the way PHP handles duplicated keys. Anyway, are you initializing your model in the controller? Maybe if you ensure that attribute is an array you'll get the desired behavior. If your model is a new instance, try something like this: `$scope.item = { selectedItems : [] };`.

Comment: Yes i initialize my model in the controller. Unfortunately that is giving me the same result.. :(

Comment: Since you already have a `multiple` attribute in that `<select>`, I'm not sure if this can make some difference, but try to add `ng-multiple="true"`.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't make a difference. I just managed to fix this in another way. I convert the $scope.item.selectedItems to json using angular.toJson($scope.item.selectedItems) and in SLIM i do a json_decode. I don't know if this is the best way to do this, but it's working..

Comment: Hi. You can add this solution as an answer to your own question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). It can help someone else in the future.